# What is wrong in comparing a null with an object rather than an object with a null

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, null

I just found out that I can compare `null` with an `Object` like this,

`if(null != Object)`

Rather than comparing `Object` with `null`, like

```
Object != null
```

What may go wrong if use the former approach?

Is that legal? If not then why does compiler accept it?

Comment: Why do you expect this not to work?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just a matter of taste really. Some prefer this and others prefer object != null. Personally I find Object != null easier to read.

Comment: if(null != object), null as an object is compared with another object..
and comparision reference is null insted of object

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction No. Null as a *reference* is comapared to another reference. The part after .. is meaningless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's one thing wrong about it - readability. If you want to write a clean code, you should care about the way it will be read in the future. It needs to be obvious, what it does and why it does a certain thing. If you place the "Object" to the right of the evaluation, it becomes less apparent what are you really doing. Well at least in my opinion...

Answer (score 6):

Most people say `Object != null` because it is what they are used to and so it is easier to read.

The best argument I've heard for `null != object` is to avoid bad expressions. e.g. to pickup a typo in `if (var == 1)`

```
if (var = 1) // this is valid C
if (1 = var) // this is not valid C
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of readability. If you can read your code out loud and it makes sense it is easier to understand. The second version is like Yoda-talk.. "null is not the object.." compared the "The object is not null"..

This same goes for giving your variables and methods good names.

A good reference site for writing readable code: http://www.cleancoders.com/

Comment: Do you mean Yoda-talk, as in Yoda Syntax?

Comment: Right.. http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/20/yoda-syntax-a-php-design-pattern-for-if-statements/ Only it argues for why, it a good idea is... Maybe if your German..

Answer (score 0):

It is the same. It is almost like saying  if `1 != 2`. Does this imply `2 != 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The `!=` operator behaves just as the test for equality operator `==` .

Ignoring any side effects in the expressions then (`expr1 != expr2`) and (`expr2 != expr1`) are exactly the same.

If **Object** is a variable (or constant) then (`null != Object`) is just as valid (although a little bit less readable).